# xmlhttprequest doesn't work well with phpmailer $mail->send()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

I am trying to set up an automatic email sending function using xmlhttprequest API in javascript and through phpmailer. Emails are sent successfully. However, the php response cannot be sent back to the xmlhttprequest’s onreadystatechange event. Through debugging the process, the value of xhr.readystate is 1, and then 2, and the process is done without any error or alert. Please see the following codes:
js codes with xmlhttprequest:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Usual mix-and-matching for x-browser omitted for brevity
                        var senddata = 'problem=' + dom.byId("sProblem").value + '&name=' + dom.byId("sName").value + '&email=' + dom.byId("sEmail").value + '&phone=' + dom.byId("sPhone").value
                                       + '&streets=' + dom.byId("sStreets").value + '&comments=' + dom.byId("sComments").value;

                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

                            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {                            
                                alert("Thank you for sending email ");                      
                            }
                        }

                         xhr.open('POST', 'Scripts/app/php/report.php', true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        xhr.send(senddata);
```

My php file is quite simple:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/../../../../../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";


$problem = $_POST["problem"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email  = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$streets = $_POST["streets"];
$comments = $_POST["comments"];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxx@xxx.net';
$mail->Password = 'xxx';
$mail->SetFrom('xxx@xxx.net', 'FromEmail');
$mail->addAddress('xxx@xxx.org', 'ToEmail');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'It is a test from Jing';
$mail->Body =  "Report a problem form from the KCRC website:"."<br>";
$mail->Body .= "Problem: $problem"."<br>";
$mail->Body .= "Name: $name"."<br>";
$mail->Body .= "E-mail: $email"."<br>";
$mail->Body .= "Phone: $phone"."<br>";
$mail->Body .= "Streets: $streets"."<br>";
$mail->Body .= "Comments: $comments"."<br>";


$mail->AltBody =  "Report a problem form from the KCRC website:"."<br>";
$mail->AltBody .= "Problem: $problem"."<br>";
$mail->AltBody .= "Name: $name"."<br>";
$mail->AltBody .= "E-mail: $email"."<br>";
$mail->AltBody .= "Phone: $phone"."<br>";
$mail->AltBody .= "Streets: $streets"."<br>";
$mail->AltBody .= "Comments: $comments"."<br>";

if(!$mail->send()) { 
  echo "Mail sending failed."; 
}else{
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}
```

When I comment this part out:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mail sending failed."; 
  }else{
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }
```

I can get this alert:  alert("Thank you for sending email ");
But if I uncomment it, the email is  sent, but no alert (the readystate never reach to 4). I need the alert to inform users that their email is sent.

I see no errors if I just run the php file: here is the result of the php page when I set debug level as 2:

```
debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220     CY4PR16CA0044.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 20 Mar 2017 12:46:59 +0000 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-CY4PR16CA0044.outlook.office365.com Hello [96.61.212.2] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-CY4PR16CA0044.outlook.office365.com Hello [96.61.212.2] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: d2ViZm9ybXN1Ym1pdEBrZW50Y291bnR5cm9hZHMubmV0 debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: eDd1Vyd5LmA/Xw== debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host BL2PR14MB0929.namprd14.prod.outlook.com debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Start mail input; end with . debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 08:46:59 -0400 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: To: ToEmail  debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: From: FromEmail  debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: It is a test from Jing debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <2e72266fdeacea641e142a9ffab0a19c@localhost> debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.15 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_2e72266fdeacea641e142a9ffab0a19c" debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format. debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_2e72266fdeacea641e142a9ffab0a19c debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Report a problem form from the KCRC website:
Problem: 
Name: 
E-mail: 
Phone: 
Streets: 
Comments: 
debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_2e72266fdeacea641e142a9ffab0a19c debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: Report a problem form from the KCRC website:
Problem: 
Name: 
E-mail: 
Phone: 
Streets: 
Comments: 
debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_2e72266fdeacea641e142a9ffab0a19c-- debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: . debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.6.0 <2e72266fdeacea641e142a9ffab0a19c@localhost> [InternalId=32800665241380, Hostname=BL2PR14MB0929.namprd14.prod.outlook.com] 3051 bytes in 0.544, 5.468 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery debug level 2; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission     channel Thank you for using our mail form
```

I've updated the phpmailer to version 5.2.23.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Those echo statements will prevent the XHR response from being interpreted correctly.

Comment: I tried both : only keep $mail->send() and get no response; only keep echo "Mail sending successfully" , and get response successfully. So at this point I assume that $mail->send() prevent the response somehow

Comment: No, send will do nothing to responses, unless you have an error of some kind - test the PHP part by itself, make sure script runs properly and responses are correct before getting it to work with XHR.

Comment: It seems like it passed the result : without enabling the debug, I got the echo response　"Thank you for using our mail form". I also enabled the debug by setting it to level 3. Please see the result below in the following post